# someVariable = { somethingThatLooksLikeAFunction }; possible?

Tags: programming

Wasn't sure how to title this question...

I was curious whether the title example is possible somehow, and are there any good tricks to using it?

I have been using something similar quite a lot:

```
newBool = (someTest) ? true:false;
newInt  = (x + (y / z));
[...]
```

However, I was curious if it was possible to add far more conditions, almost like a function?

For some simple(*) examples:

```
someThing = { 
    int _x = aFunction(_x);
    if(_x) { 
        something = somethingElse;
        for(...){ ... }; // etc
    } else {
        /* otherStuff */
    } 
};
```

Or

```
someThing = {
    for(_x=0;_x<y;_x++){
        z++;
    }
    someThing = (z>y) ? a:b;
};
```

I understand it's worth just separating it off into functions most of the time, although I'm trying to get away from a function/library-fest as much as possible...  It's getting annoying crawling through everything when I could just have the useful stuff right there, where I need it, instead of 1000 lines away, or in another library.  It also allows the text editor to fold the code out of sight, starting from one variable, instead of on each clause.

With the few tests I have tried, I've not been successful in achieving what I'm experimenting with, so, is this kind of thing possible in any way? and if so, what are the rules/possibilities/different ways you could implement this?

* Emphasis on simple! And a semi-pointless/completely useless "function" alert too!  I'm just curious about the "proof of concept" in the examples...

Comment: `Something = {code}` is just syntatic sugar for `code; something=someotherthing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `lambda` function, though the syntax is somewhat cryptic:

```
int someThing = [](int y, int z, int a, int b){
    for (int _x = 0; _x < y; _x++) {
        z++;
    }
    return (z > y) ? a : b;
}(100, 0, 10, 20);
```

In that you are defining a lamda function `[]` with four parameters, `y`, `z`, `a` and `b`. Then calling that function with four numbers `(100, 0, 10, 20)` and assigning the return value to `someThing`.

It's the same as writing a normal function but there's a lot more brackets around.

Comment: That gave me inner smiles :D That's a really nice example! Thank you!  I assume _(100, 0, 10, 20)_ could be _(intOne, intTwo, boolOne, boolTwo)_, for example, too?

Comment: Yep. Just like calling any function.

Comment: I just don't understand what is the gain doing this. It's overkill using lambdas for something you can in-line for the same result with less code.

Comment: @LookAlterno No benefit at all. The compiler will probably optimize it away anyway. But.. why climb a mountain...? Cus it's there.

Comment: Then, some time latter, some poor soul have to mantain that code ...

Comment: @LookAlterno - I'd massively appreciate any advice or alternate ways if you have any? Reason I asked is that as my program is getting larger, I am ending up with many functions that are used only within a single other function; which is becoming increasingly cumbersome to keep track of.  With something similar to the above, I can just have the "simple but still important" function there and then where I need it, and the text editor folds away to a single variable, instead of on each `for`, `if`, etc that each variable pipeline is going through.  I find it far more readable for my uses, so far.

Comment: @Timeless. WIthout actual samples of your code is hard to add anything. I use lots of small functions (<20 loc), writing them as I needed. When the code grow too much and start to look complicated, it's time to refactor it until it become manageable again.